# how to replace entire css text with another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coding-style, stylesheet

I have web page with different styles that the user can change and build  on the fly.
I have this code working with browsers IE-9+,chrome,FF,safari.

```
if($("#customCss").length>0)
     $("#customCss").empty();

$("#customCss").text(css_txt );
$('head').append('<style type="text/css" id="customCss"> ' + css_txt + '</style>');
```

I want to fit the site to IE-7,8. But this code not working with IE-7,8. I am getting this error code:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
```

in this jquery func jquery  :

```
append: function () {
            return this.domManip(arguments, true, function (elem) {
                if (this.nodeType === 1) {
                    this.appendChild(elem);
                }
            });
        },
```

I have try this also with no luck :

```
document.getElementById("customCss").innerHTML=css_txt;
```

any idea why?

Comment: Try using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to define `<style type="text/css" id="customCss">` before you try to set its contents with `$("#customCss").text(css_txt );`. You may also consider to run the code onLoad so that you're sure the #customCss element exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a reference to the `link` tag and then modify the `href` to the new script if it's an external script. If it's internal, try removing the old one with `.remove()` and `.append()` a new one right after the `<body>`.

Comment: the .remove() and then .append() again instead of .empty() did the work.Thanks.